# Got stuck in python code which made me confused

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert from below (using python code)

1. `$a` to `context('a')`
2. `#g` to `intents('g').is_()`
3. `!#g` to `intents('g').isNot_()`
4. `@c` to `entities('c').any_()`
5. `@c:ge` to `entities('c').is_('ge')`

First one I have done with but I am not finding a proper way to do it.
This is what I have tried for 1:

```
 import re
 from itertools import groupby

 class context:
    grammar= r'and|or|#|\$|:|@|\w+'

    def __init__(self, val):
       self.val = val

    def __repr__(self):   
           return "context('{}')".format(self.parse()[1])
    def parse(self):
           return re.findall(self.grammar, self.val)

 c = context("$a")    #Input
```

Output:

```
context('a') #1. $a To context('a')
```

Comment: what do you have in first code ? In what language ?

Comment: First code is not code.These are 5 format that's what I wanted to convert. i have tried to solve first point @furas

Comment: can't you use normal `replace("$a", "context('a')")` ? Or they means something more ?

Comment: Nope ! I want to have proper and stable way. @furas Please have look on above code what I have tried...

Comment: maybe you should use `if/else` to handle every rule separatelly.

Comment: if you try to create parser then maybe you should use [PLY (Python-Lex-Yacc)](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html)

Comment: Can you please show me how to use on this with sample example solve any of them above points?

Comment: This is unclear. Can you rephrase or explain things more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```py
import re

class context:
    grammar =  r'and|or|#|\$|:|@|\w+'
    subs = [
        (r'\$(\w+)', "context('\\1')"),
        (r'!#(\w+)', "intents('\\1').isNot_()"),
        (r'#(\w+)', "intents('\\1').is_()"),
        (r'@(\w+):(\w+)', "entities('\\1').is_('\\2')"),
        (r'@(\w+)', "entities('\\1').any()")
    ]

    def __init__(self, val):
       self.val = val

    def parse(self):
        parsed = self.val
        for sub in self.subs:
            parsed = re.sub(*sub, parsed)
        return parsed
```

```py
>>> print(context('$foo\n#foo\n!#foo\n@foo\n@foo:bar').parse())
context('foo')
intents('foo').is_()
intents('foo').isNot_()
entities('foo').any()
entities('foo').is_('bar')
```

Comment: Let me check and I'll get back to you. @Seb

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you try to do but to convert it I would use `re.sub()`

```
import re

text = '$a AND #g OR !#g WITH @c BUT @c:ge AGAIN $start @hello:world BYE #end'

text = re.sub('\$(\w+)', r'content(\1)', text)
text = re.sub('!#(\w+)', r'intents(\1).isNot_()', text) # `!#g` has to be before `#g`
text = re.sub('#(\w+)', r'intents(\1).is_()', text)
text = re.sub('@(\w+):(\w+)', r'entities(\1).is_(\2)', text) # `@c:ge` has to be before `@c`
text = re.sub('@(\w+)', r'entities(\1).any_()', text)

print(text)
```

Result

```
content(a) AND intents(g).is_() OR intents(g).isNot_() WITH entities(c).any_() BUT entities(c).is_(ge) AGAIN content(start) entities(hello).is_(world) BYE intents(end).is_()
```

---

If you have more complex text to convert then you should show it in question

Comment: I think so...Let me check @furas.